# Django Forms: KeyError when trying to validate felid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my form.py I'm getting the following error (below) is there anything I have missed that could be explained to me? All I'm trying to do it clean/validate the confirm password field

This is the error:

```
KeyError at /member/registration/
'passwordConfirm'

response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Users/user/Documents/workspace/project/member/forms.py in clean_password, line 27
```

forms.py

```
def clean_password(self):
    password = self.cleaned_data['password']
    passwordConfirm = self.cleaned_data['passwordConfirm']
    if password != passwordConfirm:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Password does not match, try again.")
    return password
    strong text
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Member (models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

def createUserCallBacks(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    member, new = Member.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(createUserCallBacks, User)
```

view.py

```
def registration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/error')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'],email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password=form.changed_data['password'])
            user.save()
            member = User.get_profile()
            member.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            member.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile')
        else:
            return render_to_response('pageRegistration.html', {'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    else: 
        form = RegistrationForm 
        context = {'form':form}
        return render_to_response('pageRegistration.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check form for two fields you should do that in `clean()` method rather than individual fields clean method.

Problem that you are seeing is, while you are in `clean_password` method, `cleaned_data` do not contain value for `'passwordConfirm'`. i.e its clean method - `clean_passwordConfirm()` is not called yet.

Documentation at [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Sample code:

```
def clean(self):
    try:
        cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data['password']
        passwordConfirm = cleaned_data['passwordConfirm']
        if password != passwordConfirm:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password does not match, try again.")
        return cleaned_data
    except:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Password does not match, try again.")
```

Comment: so i create a new def clean(self): in the forms.py and add the two clean_username and clean_password within that function?

Comment: You don't need to add you method in function, but write `clean(self)` to check two fields are same. See the sample code.